# Moles and Stubs on build server

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moles, pex-and-moles

I'm trying to get our team to use Moles and Stubs primarily to Mole out static classes.  One thing I need to find out is do I have to install moles and stubs using the installation program on my build servers?  Or can I just deploy the dependencies with my code so that the moled out tests run on my build server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have has problems with running Pex and Moles on the build server, until we installed the package on the build machine itself. It actually requires a dedicated target to be able to deal with the specific Moles project types. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/releasenotes.aspx.

So, you will need to install Pex and Moles on your build server to run without problems.

Comment: booh that really sucks! Basically we have an XCopy deploy policy here so installation packages are a no, no.

Comment: This post confirms my own experience: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/pex/thread/772b0aa8-47e2-4d16-be6a-aaf2d83d9f0f

Comment: Yeah I'm not booing you I'm booing the fact that I have to run some installation process to be able to run Moles on my build server.  Definitely appreciate your feedback.